# How to get multiple urls http and https using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

```
http:\/\/embed.(.*).com\/\?id=([0-9]+)

$userAgent  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D)'));
```

is there anyway to get both http and https with the above code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: What has the added code got to do with the question?!

Comment: Biffen sorry Im a starter with regex maybe Im wrong but this is the first time that Im working with this type of codes, Im just learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an optional pattern `s?` (`s` will match an `s` and `?` will make the regex engine match it one or zero times):

```
https?:\/\/embed\.(.*)\.com\/\?id=([0-9]+)
    ^^
```

I also think you forgot to escape the dots after `embed` and before `com`. You also might want to replace `(.*)` with `([^\/]*)` to avoid overflowing across `/` separated URL sections, so consider using

```
https?:\/\/embed\.([^\/]*)\.com\/\?id=([0-9]+)
```

Comment: Thankyou Wiktor thanks for your reply but I didnt add all my code I just edited my question again, Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean.

Comment: Nothink Wiktor you solved my problem thankyou Im gonna add this answer as resolved